# Push changes on many files into separate branches

Tags: git

Our junior worked on 5-6 tasks and did not create a branch for each task before starting to work on it, but just started making changes remaining on the `Master`. Now, we have dozens of files changed (modified, deleted and new files) and even dozen that are still not in the Git. Good thing **he did not make any commit or push to the remote**.

Is there a way that I can now make things right by creating multiple branches (such as `feature-1`, `feature-2`,...) and push the right files into them? So I would push 10 files to `feature-1`, 25 to `feature-2` and so on.

I tried to create a new branch from the current state, but (expectedly) the branch I've just created includes all changed files.

Another thing. We keep Git on the remote repo which has not been synced with the local repo (junior never committed or pushed to this remote). I tried creating a branch on the remote as it will not include the local changes, BUT when I try to checkout to it, Git complaints that it cannot checkout as it would overwrite changes made in a few files.

What shall I do now?

Could stash help here? I have never worked with it nor I have ever stashed files when switching to another repo. I always work in a clean way - first commit, then checkout another repo.

Comment: Stash is your friend in this situation, I will try to compose an answer unless someone gets it done before me :)

Comment: @e.doroskevic Let's see who gets there first :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hahaha :D challange accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `git stash` would be one solution here.

First, stash all the work from your junior:

```
git stash
```

**Step two:**

Next, create a new branch which will contain one set of files.  But first, pull the latest changes from the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b feature1
```

Now apply the stash:

```
git stash apply
```

This will bring back *all* the changed files, including those which you *don't* want to be in the `feature1` branch.  Add all the files you do want via:

```
git add <path/to/file1>
git add <path/to/file2>
# etc.
```

Now make a commit on `feature1` and push it to the repository:

```
git commit -m 'Junior commit with first set of files'
git push origin feature1
```

Now, the first set of file changes are safely in a remote branch of their own.  But the working directory should still contain the other changed files.  Once again, stash them away via:

```
git stash
```

Now you can return to Step two above, create a new branch, and continue this set of steps until you have committed all file changes to their own respective branches.

When there is nothing left to stash, then you have finished handling all of your junior's work.

Answer (score 2):

### Example

Let's add some files to *staging area*

```
git add <file1> <file2>
```

Run

```
git stash save "<stash message>"
```

The above instruction will stash everything in your *staging area*

Run git stash list to get a list of stashed log

```
git stash list
```

Finally, apply the stash to a branch

```
git stash branch <branch> stash@{id}
```

***Note:*** id is a number

Also, if you want to have a bit more control on what's being stashed - here are some options you can pass to stash command.

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

The above option `--keep-index` will cause *staging area* to be ***NOT*** stashed

What you can also do is

```
git stash save --include-untracked
```

The above option `--include-untracked` will cause *untracked* files to be stashed also

### Reference

[git-stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

Comment: Thanks. Tim's reply is a bit more close to what I exactly need. Upvote for you efforts.

Comment: @sandalone appreciate that, thank you. he was first to respond to your question anyway :D so I think its well deserved

Answer (score 1):

Don't fear, it's simple and straightforward.

You should not even need to use `git stash`, the basic `git add` ... `git commit` will be just fine. The trick is to use `git gui` to painlessly only add specific lines/chunks and not whole files.

If you start out in `master` with all kinds of uncommitted and unadded files, then:

```
git checkout -b branch1
git gui
# add all the individual parts you want to have in branch1
git commit

git checkout master
git checkout -b branch2
git gui
# add all the individual parts you want to have in branch2
git commit
```

And so on. (You can do linewise adds directly with `git add` of course, but I find `git gui` is very good for that, and it should be available everywhere.)